# Why make this stack exchange so intentionally useless?

Tags: discussion

[How to analyze WiFi network interference](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79449/how-to-analyze-wifi-network-interference)

It's up to the community to do what they want with this site, and I'm just one member of this community, but this Networking Engineering stack exchange seems hilariously useless. Why would you make a stack exchange about network engineering that:

1. Can't talk about non-business networks
2. Can't talk about what tools are useful for networking

No serious business network engineer is going to rely on a freaking networking stack exchange site to solve their problems, so who is this stack exchange actually targeting?

Comment: "_Can't talk about non-business networks_" That is covered by [su]. Network Engineering was split off from [su] and [sf] in order to have a space for network engineers to ask and answer questions about professionally managed networks without all the noise of home networking and consumer-grade devices that are of no interest to network engineers. [su] does a good job of supporting home/residential networking.

Comment: "_Can't talk about what tools are useful for networking_" Almost all SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se], forbid product or off-site resource recommendations. That is explained in [this Area 51 post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24050/on-proposals-soliciting-reviews-recommendations-comparisons-etc) explaining that SE does not support sites doing that.

Comment: "_No serious business network engineer is going to rely on a freaking networking stack exchange site to solve their problems,_" I guess you have not read the many questions and answers about exactly that.

Comment: I'm being hyperbolic, of course, but at 3.6 questions/day the Network Engineering stack exchange has about half the traffic of the _Quantum Computing_ exchange. When you consider there's something like 100x more network engineers than quantum computing engineers - it sure seems like a sign of a stack that, for all practical purposes, no professional network engineers use.

Comment: I have to agree -- I don't feel like I can ask any questions here.

Comment: @Gary, every SE site has a [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. Ours was decided by the community, and it explains the types of questions to ask, and it has a section about what is off-topic. We are happy to entertain good question that are on-topic. There are other SE sites that may fit questions that are off-topic here. Most SE sites forbid off-site product or resource recommendations per [this Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24050/on-proposals-soliciting-reviews-recommendations-comparisons-etc) post.

Answer (score 3):

Each community decides which topics they want to talk about - it's a majority decision and ranting won't likely change it. There are plenty of other SE sites, fitting ones even pointed out in your original question.

*Tools used by network professionals* are even explicitly *on* topic, yet *product or resource recommendations* aren't, due to them very likely attracting opinionated answers and spam.